# R: Finding the value that matches the min value of a data frame column

Tags: r

I have this simple code, which creates a data frame:

```
value1=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), ncol=1)
value2=matrix(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.01, 0.6, 0.7), ncol=1)
df=data.frame(value1, value2)
min(df$value2)
```

Here is the data frame:

```
  value1 value2
1      1   0.10
2      2   0.20
3      3   0.40
4      4   0.50
5      5   0.01
6      6   0.60
7      7   0.70
```

I want to find `value1` where `value2` is the smallest. E.g. the smallest `value2` here is `0.01`. For this value (0.01), `value1` is 5. 
I'm trying to get a something like this: 
`smallest_value1=5`.

I could only find the smallest value of `value2` which I did it with: `min(df$value2)`, but I don't know how to connect it with `value1`.

I really would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(value2==min(value2)) %>% 
  mutate(smallest_value1=value1) %>% 
  select(smallest_value1)
```

output is

```
#   A tibble: 1 x 1
#   smallest_value1
#             <int>
# 1               5
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems a job for which:

```
 df[which(df$value2 == min(df$value2)),]
```

Comment: @AndreElrico this worked for me: `smallest_value=df[which(df$value2 == min(df$value2)),]$value1` with that what you wrote I got this error: **Error in df$value1[which(df$value2 == min(df$value2)), ] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions**

Comment: `smallest_value1 <- df$value1[which(df$value2 == min(df$value2))]`

Comment: @Ville with the additional comma r expects an extra dimension. `df$value1` however is a 1-dim vector. Little slip-up :-)

Answer (score 3):

Other options include which.min:

```
df$value1[which.min(df$value2)]
```

and using the dplyr syntax:

```
library(tidyverse) 
df %>% filter(value2 == min(value2)) %>% select(value1)
```